# Overriding form events

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to override the standard sorting approach of a datagridview. How do I make the application use my function(method?) rather than the default one? This event should fire when a user clicks on a column.

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Sort stuff.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply put DataGridViewColumn.SortMode property to DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic and then implement your System.Collections.IComparer and call DataGridView1.Sort( new YourComparer( ) ) ?

Comment: @AndriyBuday But how do I make it call `DataGridView1.Sort(new YourComparer())` when the user clicks the Column header? I don't want to use a seperate button...

Comment: There is also SortCompare event. Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx . Will something like this work for your?

Comment: Also, when you seat SortMode to Programmatic isn't your method get called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this **[topic](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/248778/datagridview-my-own-sorting-method)** will be very interesting for you, as it matches for your requirements.

In general there are few techniques you can use to have your custom sorting in DataGridView, depending on your requirements.

1. Use programmatic sorting. (you would need to call Sort manually)
2. Use SortCompare event, which will be called on ColumnHeaderMouseClick. (for bound DataGridView)
3. Create your own System.Collections.IComparer.  (use for unbound datagridview)

Both are can be found at [msdn page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx).
Also please find this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95scxcdy.aspx) explaining when which technique can be used.

Comment: Thanks. I just had to add `dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);` to the Form constructor for the `DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic` to start using my method. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not *override* an event, cause event is raised *after* actual control method execution.
To *be able* to do something *before* you need to extend `DataGrid` control and override a *function* inside it, like this:

*a pesudocode*

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGridView
{
    public override void ColumnHeaderMouseClick(...)
    {
       //insert here your code and comment last line, so base class will not call it's own implementation

       base.ColumnHeaderMouseClick(...); //after execution of this, the event is reaised
    }
}
```

Riminder: this is a basic approach of how to handle this kind of situations, you have to check if this code works in *your* case.

Hope this helps.